# Java threads starting other threads, each writing into array

Tags: java, arrays, multithreading, thread-sleep, notify

Completely new to Java, however I have to, somehow, make this work. I hope You guys can get me on the right path.

The program has to create N threads and  an array of N elements. The first thread should write a random number into the array (here - `resultArray`), call (or create) the next thread (**which will do the same**) and sleep until the last thread notifies all other sleeping threads.

So, am I doing this correctly so far? How can I make the `run()` access demo's resultArray and write in the thread's random number?
Also, how can `run()` reach other threads (of the `threadList`) to notify them?

Thank You.

```
public class gijos extends Thread {

    private int length; 
    private int position;

    public gijos(int arrPos) { 
      position = arrPos;
    } 

    public int getPosition(){
       return position;
    }

    public void run() {   
             Random rand = new Random();
             int  n = rand.nextInt(51) + 1;
    }
```

---

```
public class demo { 

    public static void main (String[] args) { 

            System.out.println("Array length / thread count:");

            Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
            int N = s.nextInt();

            int[] resultArray = new int[N];

            gijos[] threadList = new gijos[N]; 

            for(int i = 0; i < N; i++){
                threadList[i] = new gijos(i);
            } 

    }

}
```

Comment: My main comment would be that if you're completely new to Java then this is not the right problem to cut your teeth on!

Comment: I totally aggree, but I was given a few lines of code that showed how to create a thread,  make it print a word and it's considered enough by some people -.- If I could figure out how to make the thread's run() write into the array and wake up other threads, I think I could figure out the rest.

Comment: notifyAll() method notifies all waiting threads.
I guess you need to learn wait(),notifyAll()

Comment: How were you given this?  Is it homework?  You should be asking your TA or professor for help, they need to know when students are having problems with an assignment.

Comment: What about writing values into the resultArray from each thread?

Comment: Make the array global. The easiest way is to define array as static.

Comment: Each thread should pass the result array and the [next] index to the next thread that it creates/starts, and waits on the array. The last thread (based on the index >= max), should notify on the array, so that other threads are woken up. A thread impl with constructor (Object[], int).

Comment: srkavin, do you still need to pass the whole array to the next thread if the array is global? Also, does 'defining array as static' mean including public static int[] resultArray; before demo's `main`? is it going to be accessible by run() as `demo.resultArray` then?

Comment: @GytisK if you're going to use static array, then you'll need to pass only the index (or) use a global/static/transient int.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you have an example worker class:

```
public class ArrayWorker implements Runnable {
    private static final List<ArrayWorker> threadList = new LinkedList<>();
    private static final Random rnd = new Random(System.currentTimeMillis());

    private final int[] array;
    private final int index;


    public ArrayWorker(final int[] array, final int index) {
        if (index > array.length - 1) {
            throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException(String.format("%d", index - array.length));
        }

        this.array = array;
        this.index = index;
        System.out.println(this + " has been created");
    }


    @Override
    public void run() {
        System.out.println(this + " run()");
        this.array[this.index] = rnd.nextInt(100);

        if (index < array.length - 2) {
            final ArrayWorker worker = new ArrayWorker(array, index + 1);

            System.out.println(this + " has created: " + worker);
            new Thread(worker).start();

            threadList.add(this);
            try {
                synchronized (this) {
                    System.out.println(this + " is now waiting");
                    this.wait();
                    System.out.println(this + " got notified");
                }
            } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                System.out.println("Error while waiting for termination");
                threadList.remove(this);
            }
        } else {
            threadList.forEach(worker -> {
                synchronized(worker) {
                    System.out.println(this + " notifying: " + worker);
                    worker.notify();
                }
            });
        }
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "WorkerThread[" + index + "]";
    }  
}
```

Here the usage:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    final int[] myArray = new int[10];

    System.out.println("MainThread creating first WorkerThread and awaiting termination of last WorkerThread");
    Thread t = new Thread(new ArrayWorker(myArray, 0));
    try {
        t.start();
        t.join();
    } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
        System.exit(-1);
    }

    System.out.println("Last WorkerThread finished");
    for (int i : myArray) {
        System.out.print(i + " ");
    }
    System.out.println();
}
```

**Example output**:

```
MainThread creating first WorkerThread and awaiting termination of last WorkerThread
WorkerThread[0] has been created
WorkerThread[0] run()
WorkerThread[1] has been created
WorkerThread[0] has created: WorkerThread[1]
WorkerThread[1] run()
WorkerThread[0] is now waiting
WorkerThread[2] has been created
WorkerThread[1] has created: WorkerThread[2]
WorkerThread[1] is now waiting
WorkerThread[2] run()
WorkerThread[3] has been created
WorkerThread[2] has created: WorkerThread[3]
WorkerThread[2] is now waiting
WorkerThread[3] run()
WorkerThread[3] notifying: WorkerThread[2]
WorkerThread[3] notifying: WorkerThread[1]
WorkerThread[2] got notified
WorkerThread[3] notifying: WorkerThread[0]
WorkerThread[1] got notified
WorkerThread[0] got notified
Last WorkerThread finished
Results:
10 25 73 7
```

Comment: Thank You. Exactly what I needed. I have a few questions if you don't mind: 
1. Are the @Override's really needed? (This won't be actually 'used' anywhere, just a task)
2. What difference does the 'final' make in this program?
3. Is there some way to make the result print always show up in the end? If I run it a few times it prints the result so fast that the thread start messages are at the end :D

Comment: @GytisK **1.** It is not really needed, just a good coding style and helps the compiler to help you to prevent errors. **2.** Again, this is a good practice helping you to minimize the chance of producing bugs. **3.** Yes there is, you have to use a logger (that will preserve the order of debug messages and print them fifo)

Comment: Without threadList, how would I notify all the threads with the last thread? I used (in main) else { synchronized(this){this.notifyAll()} } and it's not stopping the program when done.